# ngModel outside ngFor scope

Tags: html, angular

I have  a form-group with input inside a bootstrap card:

```html
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-label" for="name"><b>Dish name: </b></label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control"
          required minlength="1"
          [(ngModel)]="dish.name" #dishName="ngModel"
          placeholder="name"
          />
        <div *ngIf="dishName.invalid && (dishName.dirty || dishName.touched)"
          class="alert alert-danger">

          <div *ngIf="dishName.errors?.['required']">
            Name is required.
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

For the footer I use **dishName**:

```html
      <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-evenly">
        <a class="btn btn-warning" (click)="goBack()">Go back</a>
        <a class="btn btn-success" *ngIf="dishName.valid" (click)="updateDish()">Update dish</a>
        <a class="btn btn-secondary" *ngIf="dishName.invalid" style="pointer-events: none; cursor: default;">Update dish</a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteDish()">Delete dish</a>
      </div>
```

In the card I create smaller cards with *ngFor:

```html
<div class="col" *ngFor="let componentDetail of dishWithComponentDetails.components; index as i">
          <div class="card card-hover h-100" *ngIf="componentDetail">
            <div class="card-header">
              <small class="text-muted"><b>{{ componentDetail.name | uppercase }}</b></small>

            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              
              <h5 class="card-text">Total cost: {{ dish.components[i].componentQuantity * componentDetail.price }} kr</h5>
              <h6 class="card-text">Component price: {{ dish.components[i].componentQuantity }} {{ componentDetail.unit }} @ {{ componentDetail.price }} kr / {{ componentDetail.unit }}</h6>
              
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-label" for="componentQuantity"><b>Quantity: </b></label>
                <input type="number" id="componentQuantity" name="componentQuantity" class="form-control"
                  required minlength="1"
                  [(ngModel)]="dish.components[i].componentQuantity" #componentQuantity="ngModel"
                  placeholder="quantity"
                  
                  />
                <div *ngIf="componentQuantity.invalid && (componentQuantity.dirty || componentQuantity.touched)"
                  class="alert alert-danger">
        
                  <div *ngIf="componentQuantity.errors?.['required']">
                    Quantity is required.
                  </div>
        
                </div>
              </div>
              
            </div>

            <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-evenly">
              <a class="btn btn-primary" routerLink="/components/{{ componentDetail._id }}">See details</a>
              <a class="btn btn-danger">Remove</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

The above works, and the updateDish() as well.

However, I would like to also check valid/invalid of #componentQuantity="ngModel", like:

```html
      <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-evenly">
        <a class="btn btn-warning" (click)="goBack()">Go back</a>
        <a class="btn btn-success" *ngIf="dishName.valid && componentQuantity.valid" (click)="updateDish()">Update dish</a>
        <a class="btn btn-secondary" *ngIf="dishName.invalid  && componentQuantity.invalid" style="pointer-events: none; cursor: default;">Update dish</a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteDish()">Delete dish</a>
      </div>
```

which yields the error:

> TS2339: Property 'componentQuantity' does not exist on type 'DishDetailComponent'.

My guess is that **#componentQuantity="ngModel"** is inside the scope of **ngFor="let componentDetail of dishWithComponentDetails.components; index as i"** and thus doesn't excist outside of the ngFor.

The alert-div for the componentQuantity works fine.

**The question is, how can I declare the variable for valid or invalid input of componentQuantity outside the ngFor? Can I declare an array with all #componentQuantity? What is the best approach?**

Complete html (no error variant):

```html
<div class="container" *ngIf="dish">
  <div class="p-3"></div>
  <div class="card" *ngIf="dishWithComponentDetails$ | async as dishWithComponentDetails">
    <div class="card-header">
      <small class="text-muted">dish id: {{ dish._id }}</small>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h2 class="card-title">{{ dish.name | uppercase }} Details</h2>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-label" for="name"><b>Dish name: </b></label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control"
          required minlength="1"
          [(ngModel)]="dish.name" #dishName="ngModel"
          placeholder="name"
          />
        <div *ngIf="dishName.invalid && (dishName.dirty || dishName.touched)"
          class="alert alert-danger">

          <div *ngIf="dishName.errors?.['required']">
            Name is required.
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <p class="card-text"><b>Total cost:</b> {{dish.totalCost}}</p>
      <h3>Components:</h3>
      <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4">
        <div class="col" *ngFor="let componentDetail of dishWithComponentDetails.components; index as i">
          <div class="card card-hover h-100" *ngIf="componentDetail">
            <div class="card-header">
              <small class="text-muted"><b>{{ componentDetail.name | uppercase }}</b></small>

            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              
              <h5 class="card-text">Total cost: {{ dish.components[i].componentQuantity * componentDetail.price }} kr</h5>
              <h6 class="card-text">Component price: {{ dish.components[i].componentQuantity }} {{ componentDetail.unit }} @ {{ componentDetail.price }} kr / {{ componentDetail.unit }}</h6>
              
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-label" for="componentQuantity"><b>Quantity: </b></label>
                <input type="number" id="componentQuantity" name="componentQuantity" class="form-control"
                  required minlength="1"
                  [(ngModel)]="dish.components[i].componentQuantity" #componentQuantity="ngModel"
                  placeholder="quantity"
                  
                  />
                <div *ngIf="componentQuantity.invalid && (componentQuantity.dirty || componentQuantity.touched)"
                  class="alert alert-danger">
        
                  <div *ngIf="componentQuantity.errors?.['required']">
                    Quantity is required.
                  </div>
        
                </div>
              </div>
              
            </div>

            <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-evenly">
              <a class="btn btn-primary" routerLink="/components/{{ componentDetail._id }}">See details</a>
              <a class="btn btn-danger">Remove</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-hover">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-title">Add component to dish</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="p-3"></div>
      <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-evenly">
        <a class="btn btn-warning" (click)="goBack()">Go back</a>
        <!-- here i would also like to check componentQuantity.valid -->
        <a class="btn btn-success" *ngIf="dishName.valid" (click)="updateDish()">Update dish</a>
        <a class="btn btn-secondary" *ngIf="dishName.invalid" style="pointer-events: none; cursor: default;">Update dish</a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteDish()">Delete dish</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

## Solution:

```ts
  @ViewChildren('componentQuantity') listComponentQuantity!: QueryList<NgModel>;

  quantitiesAreValid: boolean = true;

  // returns true if all componentQuantity is .valid, otherwise false
  componentQuantitiesValid() {
    this.listComponentQuantity.forEach(element => {
      if (element.invalid) {
        console.log("return: false");
        this.quantitiesAreValid = false;
        return;
      }
      else {
        console.log("return: true");
      }
    });
    console.log("valid quantities: " + this.quantitiesAreValid);
    return this.quantitiesAreValid = true;
  }
```

## Unanswered (new question)

**How do I run the function *componentQuantitiesValid()* continuously on input change?**
See [How to run validation function on input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76898057/how-to-run-validation-function-on-input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "reach" a "template reference variable" outside scope, you need use ViewChildren in .ts

```
@ViewChildren('componentQuantity') listComponentQuantity:QueryList<NgModel>
```

Then you can "reach" the "i element" using a function

```
getQuantityAt(index:number)
{
    return this.listComponentQuantity.find((_:any,i:number)=>i==index)
}
```

And use,e.g.

```
   {{getQuantityAt(0).value}}
```

Another way can be use a getter converting in array the queryList

```
get arrayCuantity()
{
   return this.listComponentQuantity.toArray()
}
```

And use

```
   {{arrayQuantity[0].value}}
```

Comment: Thank you! I needed a '!', don't know why: @ViewChildren('componentQuantity') listComponentQuantity!: QueryList<NgModel>;. Also, I wrote a function to return true if all componentQuantity is valid, otherwise false. But don't know how to implement into the html. With a button, running the fn I see I get the desired result. But I want to run the fn continuously on input change? Thanks!

Comment: @Robbas, in "strictmode", you use "!" in ViewChild and ViewChildren to indicate to the "Angular" that this variable you don't initialize, but "that you know what are doing"

Comment: knowWhatImDoing definitely returns false.