# How to run validation function on input?

Tags: angular

This is a follow up from this question:
[ngModel outside ngFor scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76892963/ngmodel-outside-ngfor-scope/)

I create cards with input in a ngFor:

```html
        <div class="col" *ngFor="let componentDetail of dishWithComponentDetails.components; index as i">
          <div class="card card-hover h-100" *ngIf="componentDetail">
            <div class="card-header">
              <small class="text-muted"><b>{{ componentDetail.name | uppercase }}</b></small>

            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              
              <h5 class="card-text">Total cost: {{ dish.components[i].componentQuantity * componentDetail.price }} kr</h5>
              <h6 class="card-text">Component price: {{ dish.components[i].componentQuantity }} {{ componentDetail.unit }} @ {{ componentDetail.price }} kr / {{ componentDetail.unit }}</h6>
              
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-label" for="componentQuantity"><b>Quantity: </b></label>
                <input type="number" id="componentQuantity" name="componentQuantity" class="form-control"
                  required minlength="1"
                  [(ngModel)]="dish.components[i].componentQuantity" #componentQuantity="ngModel"
                  placeholder="quantity"
                  />
                <div *ngIf="componentQuantity.invalid && (componentQuantity.dirty || componentQuantity.touched)"
                  class="alert alert-danger">
        
                  <div *ngIf="componentQuantity.errors?.['required']">
                    Quantity is required.
                  </div>
        
                </div>
              </div>
              
            </div>

            <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-evenly">
              <a class="btn btn-primary" routerLink="/components/{{ componentDetail._id }}">See details</a>
              <a class="btn btn-danger">Remove</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I validate the input of each componentQuantity:

```html
      <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-evenly">
        <a class="btn btn-warning" (click)="goBack()">Go back</a>
        <a class="btn btn-warning" (click)="componentQuantitiesValid()">Log componentQuantitiesValid()</a>
        <a class="btn btn-success" *ngIf="dishName.valid && quantitiesAreValid" (click)="updateDish()">Update dish</a>
        <a class="btn btn-secondary" *ngIf="dishName.invalid || !quantitiesAreValid" style="pointer-events: none; cursor: default;">Update dish</a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteDish()">Delete dish</a>
      </div>
```

Here's the TS:

```ts
  @ViewChildren('componentQuantity') listComponentQuantity!: QueryList<NgModel>;
  
  quantitiesAreValid: Boolean = true;
  // returns true if all componentQuantity is .valid, otherwise false
  componentQuantitiesValid() {
    this.quantitiesAreValid = true;
    this.listComponentQuantity.forEach(element => {
      if (element.invalid) {
        console.log("return: false");
        this.quantitiesAreValid = false;
        return;
      }
      else {
        console.log("return: true");
      }
    });
    console.log("valid quantities: " + this.quantitiesAreValid);
    return this.quantitiesAreValid;
  }
```

## Question:

How do I run the validation function `componentQuantitiesValid()` on input change? Right now I have to press the temporary button 'Log componentQuantitiesValid()'. I tried just to add it to the `<input>`:

```html
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-label" for="componentQuantity"><b>Quantity: </b></label>
                <input type="number" id="componentQuantity" name="componentQuantity" class="form-control"
                  required minlength="1"
                  [(ngModel)]="dish.components[i].componentQuantity" #componentQuantity="ngModel"
                  placeholder="quantity"
                  componentQuantitiesValid <!-- THIS DOES NOTHING -->
                  />
                <div *ngIf="componentQuantity.invalid && (componentQuantity.dirty || componentQuantity.touched)"
                  class="alert alert-danger">
        
                  <div *ngIf="componentQuantity.errors?.['required']">
                    Quantity is required.
                  </div>
        
                </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run the validation function on input change, you can use the (ngModelChange) event binding

```
<input 
  type="number"
  [(ngModel)]="dish.components[i].componentQuantity"
  (ngModelChange)="onQuantityChange($event)"
>
```

add the function to the TS:

```
onQuantityChange(newValue) {
  this.componentQuantitiesValid(); 
}
```

Other note:

Rather than setting quantitiesAreValid to true initially, set it to false and only set to true if valid. This avoids an extra assignment.

Comment: wow that was easy, I was playing around with all the Component Lifecycle Events xD

Thank you! Also, thank you for the pro tip reversing the bool.